# code part I do not understand

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I don't understand why in this code, it's do that:

```
query.setString("idFamilleDeProduit", String.valueOf(familleDeProduits.getFamilleDeProduitsGenerique().getId()));
```

When I looked my table in my database, `id` column is `integer`.

it's PostgreSql-9.4.1207

***my function:***

```
public List<ContratMdd> recherchePourDuplication(String typeAccord, FamilleDeProduitsNomenclature familleDeProduits, SocieteInterne societeInterne, SocieteExterne societeExterne, String anneeAccord) throws PersistenceException {

    List<ContratMdd> listContratMdd = new ArrayList<ContratMdd>();

    String requete = "";

    if (!"".equals(anneeAccord)){
        requete += " anneeAccord = :anneeAccord";
    }
    if (!"".equals(typeAccord) && ! "".equals(requete)){
        requete += " AND";
    }
    if (!"".equals(typeAccord)){
        requete += " type = :type";
    }

    boolean existFamille = false;

    requete += (familleDeProduits != null && familleDeProduits.getFamilleDeProduitsGenerique() != null) ? " AND " : "";

    if(familleDeProduits != null && familleDeProduits.getFamilleDeProduitsGenerique() != null){
        existFamille = true;
        requete += " estAppliqueSur.familleDeProduitsGenerique IS NOT NULL AND  estAppliqueSur.familleDeProduitsGenerique.id = :idFamilleDeProduit";
    }


    boolean existSocieteInterne = false;
    boolean existSocieteExterne = false;

    requete += (societeInterne != null) ? " AND " : "";

    if(societeInterne != null){

        existSocieteInterne = true;
        String table = societeInterne instanceof Master ? "MasterImpl" : "AdherentImpl";
        requete += " contractantInterne.id = :idsocieteInterne AND contractantInterne IN (FROM "+table+") ";
    }

    requete += (societeExterne != null) ? " AND " : "";

    if(societeExterne!=null){

        existSocieteExterne = true;
        String table = societeExterne instanceof GroupeIndustriel ? "GroupeIndustrielImpl" : "FournisseurImpl";
        requete += " contractantExterne.id = :idsocieteExterne AND contractantExterne IN (FROM "+table+") ";

    }


    if (!"".equals(requete)) {

        requete = "from ContratMddImpl where" + requete;
        Query query = createQuery(requete);

        if (!"".equals(anneeAccord)){
            query.setBigInteger("anneeAccord", new BigInteger(anneeAccord));
        }
        if (!"".equals(typeAccord)){
            query.setString("type", typeAccord);
        }
        if(existFamille){
            query.setString("idFamilleDeProduit", String.valueOf(familleDeProduits.getFamilleDeProduitsGenerique().getId()));
        }
        if (existSocieteInterne){
            query.setInteger("idsocieteInterne", societeInterne.getId());
        }
        if (existSocieteExterne){
            query.setInteger("idsocieteExterne", societeExterne.getId());
        }

        listContratMdd.addAll((List<ContratMdd>) query.list());     
    }

    return listContratMdd;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because the Postgre's DB Driver allows it. But you should be using `setInt()` instead of `setString()` for an `Integer` as other DB Drivers might not support it.

Here is what `java.sql.PreparedStatement` Documentation has to say:

> Note: The setter methods (setShort, setString, and so on) for setting
>   IN parameter values must specify types that are compatible with the
>   defined SQL type of the input parameter. For instance, if the IN
>   parameter has SQL type INTEGER, then the method setInt should be used.

Comment: I think it is no longer supported on the latest version of postgresql-9.4.1207 jdbc driver. With my code i have this error: `could not extract ResultSet` `ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying`